# ReactJS Uppy - Show images in uppy dashboard after state changes | How prefill/preload images in uppy.io library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, uppy

I am using Uppy Dashboard and whenever the state changes uppy reset its state and the uploaded images are not shown. How can I add/show images in my uppy? How prefill/preload images in uppy.io library?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks
Below is my code:

```
    const equipment_uppy = new Uppy({
      id: 'equipment_uppy',
      restrictions: { allowedFileTypes: ['image/*', 'video/*'] },
      autoProceed: false
    })
   
    equipment_uppy.on('file-added', (file) => {
      equipment_uppy.setFileMeta(file.id, {
        type: file.source,
        avintakeid : data.id
      })
    })
   
    equipment_uppy.use(XHRUpload, {
    endpoint: `${process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_URL}/api/auth/uploadavintakeimages`,
    formData: true,
    fieldName: 'files[]',
    headers: {
     Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
    }})
    
     
    equipment_uppy.use(Webcam)

<Dashboard   
uppy={equipment_uppy}  
id='equipment_location_image'
width='100%'
height='300px'
plugins={['Webcam']}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure you have latest version of the Uppy core & Uppy react NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/uppy**. After that pls initialize in this way

```
import Uppy from '@uppy/core'
import XHRUpload from '@uppy/xhr-upload'
import Webcam from '@uppy/webcam'  
import { DragDrop, Dashboard, useUppy } from '@uppy/react' 

    const equipment_uppy = useUppy(() => {
        return new Uppy({
        id: 'equipment_uppy',
        restrictions: { allowedFileTypes: ['image/*', 'video/*'] }, 
        autoProceed: false
        }) 
        .use(XHRUpload, { 
        endpoint: `${process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_URL}/api/auth/uploadapi`, 
        formData: true,
        fieldName: 'files[]', 
        headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
        }})  
  })
  
  equipment_uppy.on('file-added', (file) => {  
      equipment_uppy.setFileMeta(file.id, {
        type: file.source,
        avintakeid : data.id
      })  
  })  
  
  equipment_uppy.on('file-removed', (file) => {
     console.log(file)
  })
     
 equipment_uppy.on('complete', function(result) {  
    console.log(result)
  })
  
<Dashboard 
 uppy={equipment_uppy}
id='equipment_location_image'
width='100%'
height='180px' 
>  
</Dashboard>
```

I hope this works
Thanks